# Slow file transfer from & between iMacs

Tags: macos, wifi, imac, usb, performance

I have a problem with slow file transfers from & between 2 iMacs which I'm hoping you can help with.

- iMac27 is a 2009 with 12Gb RAM & a 1Tb HDD running High Sierra 10.13.6
- iMac24 is a 2007 with 4Gb RAM & a 500Gb SSD running El Capitan 10.11.6

Both the above are connected to a Sagem router by 2.4Ghz wifi. I have plugged a 32Gb USB stick into the back of the router to share files across the network, but transfering the files is very slow so I did some tests using the same file with the following results:

- iMac27 to USB stick - 143.6Mb file takes 69 seconds = 16.6Mbps
- iMac24 to USB stick - 143.6Mb file takes 73 seconds = 15.7Mbps
- iMac27 to iMac24 - 143.6Mb file takes 153 seconds = 7.5Mbps

I have tried this before with a different ISP's router but had similar results so I don't think it's the router.
Any idea what could be wrong and what I can do to improve things as I can't live with this level of data transfer.
TIA

Comment: Maybe instead of using this method, you could use AirDrop, iCloud, DropBox, Thunderbolt. I think the best option would be to use Thunderbolt and boot the one with the files needing to be teansferred into Target Disk Mode.

Comment: . @knobby is the USB required for network sharing ? doesnt Mac has its own network sharing methods ?

Comment: @todd using the local network should provide much quicker transfer rates as the network adapters in each iMac are capable of 100Mbps+ and my router 300Mbps. My internet connection is only 40Mbps.

Comment: @ankii Mac does have it's own network sharing methods which is what I am having issues with.

Comment: @Knobby oh I had misread.. So both the Macs are connected via the router, not by a direct wired connection ?

Comment: @Knobby You can try Wireless Diagnostics and you can also check your network adapter link speeds just incase in Network Utility. Wireless Diagnostics can tell you if something is wrong with the network.

Comment: You are also limited by USB 1 speeds I think.